# In postman, Increase environment variable by 1 after every collection run

Tags: javascript, postman

any idea why the following code doesn't update the id variable with 1, after the 39 tests in the collection runs?

```
var id = pm.environment.get("id");
var a = id;
mare = id + 36;
id++;
if (id > mare) {
   a = a + 1;
};
var id = pm.environment.set("id", a);
```

Comment: How do you initiate the environment variable id? Code? In the pre-request or test script? That snippet you posted, is that pre-request or test script?

Comment: All the environment variables are strings so you are also trying to add a number to a string. You would probably needed to `parseInt()` the `pm.environment.get()`